# PowerShell Script - Report specific string from filename

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to build a simple script that would report back a string from a filename

I have a directory full of files named as follows:

```
C:\[20141002134259308][302de103-6dc8-4e29-b303-5fdbd39c60c3][U0447744][10.208.15.40_54343][ABC_01].txt
C:\[20141002134239815][302de103-6dc8-4e29-b303-5fdbd39c60c3][U0011042][10.168.40.34_57350][ABC_01].txt
C:\[20141002134206386][302de103-6dc8-4e29-b303-5fdbd39c60c3][u1603381][10.132.171.132_54385][ABC_01].txt
C:\[2014100212260259][302de103-6dc8-4e29-b303-5fdbd39c60c3][U0010217][10.173.0.132_49921][ABC_01].txt
```

So, I'd like to extract from each filename the user ids that are identified starting with a letter U and  seven digits, then create a new txt o csv and have all these Ids listed. That's it.

Comment: Welcome? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

As Patrice pointed out, you really should try and do it yourself and come to us with the relevant piece of code you tried and the error that you are getting. That said, I'm bored, and this is really easy. I'd use a regex match against the name of the file, and then for each one that matched I'd output the captured string:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Path\To\Files\*.txt' | Where{$_.Name -match "\[(U\d{7})\]"} | ForEach{$Matches[1]}
```

That will return:

```
U0447744
U0011042
u1603381
U0010217
```

If you want to output it to a file, just pipe that to Out-File, and specify the full path and name of the file you want to save that in.

Comment: I understand and I thank you so much! I actually sorted it out myself (with some old post from you actually TheMadTechnician) This is what I came up with:
GCI $path | ?{$_.BaseName -match "0c3\]\[(.*?)\]"}| %{$_.CopyTo("$($_.Directory)\$($matches[1])")}| Export-Csv "C:\IAM\test\list.csv"
Loved the export-csv and its outcome, now I'm just tryng to filter and get just what I need.